# How to insert data from a CSV file into SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I wanted to know if there is any way of accessing my local hard drive to use `BULK INSERT` or another command to insert data into a SQL Server database table from a CSV file.

I've used `BULK INSERT` before but in order to use it, I had to put the CSV file on the server's hard drive, not my local hard drive. I had access to the hard disk of the computer the server was on.

This time I only have read and write access to SQL Server but not to the whole computer it is installed on.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `BULK INSERT` then you need to get the file to a place that SQL Server can see (a file share, perhaps). Or perform the `BULK INSERT` on a different server and then moving the data over to the other SQL Server via a linked server, SSIS, etc.

Of course CSV is not exactly a complex format to handle - you can easily do this from a simple C# application by either decomposing the CSV into a set and using [table-valued parameters](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql) or using [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. I created a temporary database on my local server and did a 'BULK INSERT' to a temporary table locally. I then linked my local server to the server I wanted to query. Finally, I got the inner join I wanted between the temporary table(where I bulk inserted my data into) and the main DB.

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx) to on how to create DB links

See also [the first answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers) on how to write an inner join statement on how to write an inner join between two servers.