# Linking two databases

Tags: sql-server

I have the next sentence:

```
SELECT E.Nombre,GN3Pruebas.dbo.Empleado.DirectorioActivo
FROM Intranet.dbo.Empleado E
INNER JOIN GN3Pruebas.dbo.Empleado ON GN3Pruebas.dbo.Empleado.CodigoGN2=Intranet.dbo.Empleado.IdEmpleado
and GN3Pruebas.dbo.Empleado.IdEmpleado=5075
```

And I have the next mistake:

Mens. 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "Intranet.dbo.Empleado.IdEmpleado" could not be bound. Why?. Thanks so much

Comment: This cannnot be done.  Possible suplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using an Alias `E` for `Intranet.dbo.Empleado` you will have to use the alias for your join condition

```
SELECT E.Nombre,GN3Pruebas.dbo.Empleado.DirectorioActivo
FROM Intranet.dbo.Empleado E
INNER JOIN GN3Pruebas.dbo.Empleado ON GN3Pruebas.dbo.Empleado.CodigoGN2=E.IdEmpleado
and GN3Pruebas.dbo.Empleado.IdEmpleado=5075
```