# Mysql joins whith databases across servers

Tags: mysql, join

I have tried cross DB joins it works fine. We are planning to move DB's to 2 different servers because of load. How do i write my code in codeigniter, so that joins work across server join.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta use `sp_addlinkedserver` for creating links across servers.
I guess what you need can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers).