# How to compare result of two tables present on two different database server

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Let's say we have a table on two different database server ( for eg. dev and test). I want to compare the data stored in this table.

Suppose after executing the table on the dev database server, we get 10 values and same amount of data, we get on the test database server. My concern is how to compare the values that comes in each row.

Is there any specific tool for this?

Comment: Please try to search for Linked Server. Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers

Comment: Can I use it in  sybase also ?

Comment: I think YES, Check this, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280102. Or Google "linked server query in sybase"

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for proxy tables. 
First you should create a server

```
sp_addserver 'svr_dev', ASEnterprise, '[IP ADRESS]:[PORT]'
```

Than you can create a proxy table as below

```
CREATE EXISTING TABLE proxy_test 
at "svr_dev.[db_name].[user].test"
```

It's only an example, more information you can find here

- [sp_addserver](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1550/html/sprocs/X18765.htm)
- [Reference Manual: Commands (PDF)](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/pdf/commands.pdf)

Comment: Also, if the server you are adding is in the local `interfaces` file, you only need to specify the Servername, and not the IP/port.

Answer (score 2):

If you own Replication server, you can use the tool rs_subcmp located in $SYBASE/$SYBASE_REP/bin in UNIX environment