# Join two tables from different servers with PDO

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I would like to join two tables. But these tables are on different servers. Is it possible to do it with pdo connections?

```
$con1 - server 1 connection script
$con2 - server 2 connection script
```

I know how to join in sql but strugling with php and pdo

```
$sql = $con1 -> prepare("SQL QUERY");
$sql -> execute();
```

But how todo with two servers?

Comment: The accepted answer here will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers

Comment: I know this but is nothing about pdo...