# Does someone know how can I connect multi-DB-servers for clearing code or samples

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have found out a lot of messages from stack overflow but it is too much information to me , and I didn't see any clear code ,I wish I can use like as below URLs with easy way

> [Querying data by joining two tables in two database on different servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers)
>
> [Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

PS: sorry for all , maybe my English isn't very well ,so that I cannot understand or know , hopefully someone can give me a very simple code

Comment: Hi @Wee Wei what kind of code do you want to use ??

Comment: Hi I just need to sample code on SQL Server Management Studio ( I mean pure T-SQL script )

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: But you have simple sample code in those links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample is very easy , hopefully it is you want

> 1.Data Source <=Server ip or ServerName
>           2.Initial Catalog <= DB Name
>           3.User ID  <= Account ID
>           4.Password <= Account PWD
>           5.[*****].[dbo].[awards] <= which table you want to find out

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI',
    'Data Source=10.***.***.***;Initial Catalog=B2C**;User ID=****;Password="****"')
    .[*****].[dbo].[awards]
```

PS: **more detail you can see**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/ms179856(v=sql.120).aspx

or [Querying data by joining two tables in two database on different servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers)
or [Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server)

it will be gave you more detail ways or methods