# SQL Server : need help returning information where value from Table A falls between a date range in table B

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table A Transaction details

```
TTime (datetime), TableAValues, TableAValues, <etc>...
```

Table B related table

```
ID, DateTimeStart (datetime), DateTimeEnd (datetime), TableBValues, TableBValues, <etc>...
```

I need a way to return a row of information which includes All TableAValues as well as all TableBValues where TTime Table A falls between DateTimeStart and DateTimeEnd of table B.

Comment: Have you looked at existing question on SO like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers?

Comment: Duplicate question. Do not ask same question which has been asked before by any other user.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    TableA AS A
        JOIN TableB AS B
            ON A.TTime BETWEEN B.DateTimeStart AND B.DateTimeEnd
```

Be aware that `BETWEEN` is inclusive, meaning that it will return true if `A.TTime` is the same as either `B.StartDateTime` or `B.EndDateTime`. If you want to get just the ones that truly fall between start and end you should use greater than `>` and less than `<` operators.

You should also be aware of accuracy on SQL Server, per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.110).aspx), DateTime is

> Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

Running the following queries can help illustrate:

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME = '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000',
        @TestTime DATETIME = '2016-01-01 08:00:00.008', -- rounds down to .007      
        @EndTime1 DATETIME = '2016-01-01 08:00:00.007', -- stays the same
        @EndTime2 DATETIME = '2016-01-01 08:00:00.006'; -- rounds up to .007            

SELECT 'Eh? What just happened?'
WHERE   @TestTime BETWEEN @Starttime AND @EndTime1;

SELECT 'What is going on!'
WHERE   @TestTime BETWEEN @Starttime AND @EndTime2;
```