# Combining two database table in different databases in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join

Please help me. I don't know how to combine two database table into one in two databases. I tried to combined them using mysql JOIN but, it doesn't work. I appreciated all your responses. Here is screenshots of the mysql databases:

[Dtabase 'thesis'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVOhD.png)

[Database 'thesis_carinan'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWqTx.png)

Comment: similar issue in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145637/querying-data-by-joining-two-tables-in-two-database-on-different-servers

Comment: What is your expected output?  Please include all data directly in your question, as _text_, formatted as code with four or more spaces on each line.

Comment: I wanted to get the data in 'thesis_carinan'(database) 'user' (db table) and combine them in 'thesis' (database) 'user'(db table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join between tables in two different databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/join-between-tables-in-two-different-databases)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want a union here:

```
SELECT name, gender, college, course, email, mob, password
FROM thesis.user
UNION ALL
SELECT name, gender, college, course, email, mob, password
FROM thesis_carinan.user;
```

I am suggesting a union because both your tables have identical structure, and combining via a union would seem to make more sense than using a join.

Comment: Hey Tim Biegeleisen! thank you for your response. I run your code but, I got an error message saying Table 'thesis.thesis' doesn't exist.

Comment: I am sorry but it didn't work for me when to test it. just need specify the table like `SELECT name, gender, college, course, email, mob, password FROM thesis.user
UNION ALL
SELECT name, gender, college, course, email, mob, password FROM thesis_carinan.user;`

Comment: @JohnMarkBondad I wasn't sure if these tables were really in separate databases. Just preface the table name by the database, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

From Tim Answer you can add specify Table

More like this:

```
SELECT name, gender, college, course, email, mob, password
FROM thesis.user
UNION ALL
SELECT name, gender, college, course, email, mob, password
FROM thesis_carinan.user;
```

Comment: From your answer of course i am just add table to specify.